# scipy optimize - fmin Nelder-Mead simplex

Tags: python, scipy, data-mining, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to use the scipy Nelder-Mead simplex search function to find a minimum to a non-linear function. It appears my simplex gets stuck because it starts off with an initial simplex that is too small. Unfortunately, I don't see anywhere in scipy where you can change some of the simplex parameters (e.g. initial simplex size). Is there a way? Am I missing something? Or are there other implementations of the NM simplex?

Thanks

Comment: by "stuck" you mean, you have found a local minimum?

Comment: try other initial conditions for x0, e.g. random numbers in the appropriate range, to find other minima

Comment: i mean stuck as in it always returns to the initial values i give it. likely because the local space it search does not have any value change

Comment: without seeing the code it's hard to parse what is going on here, but my gut feeling is that the function you wanna minimize actually spit out constant values in the vicinity of your initial arguments, maybe some discontinuities or illegal input parameters.

Comment: yea i think that's what's happening. I'm not sure exactly what my function looks like but there is likely to some discontinuities at certain points.

Comment: if its not high dimensional, plot it... otherwise investigate `all_vecs` and switch on `full_output, disp` for further information about convergence.

Answer (score 3):

Two suggestions for Nelder-Mead:

1) snap all `x` to a grid, say .01, inside the function:

```
x = np.round( x / grid ) * grid
f = ...
```

This acts as a simple noise filter in high dimensions
(in 2d or 3d, don't bother).

2) start off with the best d+1 of 2d+1 nearby points, 
instead of the usual d+1:

```
def neard1( func, x, h, verbose=1 ):
    """ eval func at 2d+1 points x, x +- h
        sort
        -> f[ d+1 best values ],  X[ d+1 ] 
        to start or restart Nelder-Mead
    """
    dim = len(x)
    I = np.eye(dim)
    np.fill_diagonal( I, h )  # scalar or vec
    X = x + np.vstack(( np.zeros(dim), I, - I ))
    fnear = np.array([ func( x ) for x in X ])  # 2d+1
    f0 = fnear[0]
    up = np.argsort( fnear )  # vec func: |fnear|
    if verbose:
        print "neard1: f %g +- %s  around x %s" % ( 
            f0, fnear[up] - f0, x )
    bestd1 = up[:dim+1]
    return fnear[bestd1], X[bestd1]
```

It's also not a bad idea to look at the neard1() values after Nelder-Mead,
to get an idea of what func() looks like there.
If any neighbors are better then the N-M "best", restart N-M from that new simplex.
(One can alternate neard1, N-M, neard1, N-M: easy but very problem-dependent.)

How many variables do you have, and how noisy is your function ?

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

From the reference at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/:

> Method Nelder-Mead uses the Simplex algorithm [R123], [R124]. This algorithm has been successful in many applications but other algorithms using the first and/or second derivatives information might be preferred for their better performances and robustness in general.

It may be recommended to use a completely different algorithm, then. Note that:

> Method BFGS uses the quasi-Newton method of Broyden, Fletcher, Goldfarb, and Shanno (BFGS) [R127] pp. 136. It uses the first derivatives only. BFGS has proven good performance even for non-smooth optimizations. This method also returns an approximation of the Hessian inverse, stored as hess_inv in the OptimizeResult object.

BFGS sounds more robust and faster overall.

ParagonRG

Comment: Um... thanks. I'm trying the BFGS method as well. Unfortunately, it uses first derivatives, which have to be estimated for my function using first differences. So not sure if it will be better. It might for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a more current answer in case someone comes across this. The latest implementation of `scipy.optimize.minimize()` allows you to pass in an initial simplex as an argument. See the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-neldermead.html#optimize-minimize-neldermead) for details. I've found it to be super helpful because I too had the same issue of the default initial simplex being too small.